# How to change MaterializeCSS sideNav to slide from the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Basically I'm using the materialize starter-template. Currently I got the "hamburger" button on the right side but I want the actually sideNav to open from the right side of the screen. Please help, do I change this with the js or the CSS??

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: As seen in their docs http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html You have an option `edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin` while initializing it.